# I am unable to install sudo ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=XXXXXXXX in ios

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=297123695618 --save
```

Installing `phonegap-plugin-push` for ios:

> Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined
>
> Error: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in bin_path': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
>       from /Users/sanjaychaudhary/.gem/bin/pod:22:in `<main>`
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push 
>           --variable SENDER_ID=297123695618 --save (exit code 1)